# Почему одинарный уровень косвенности позволяет передавать указатель в функцию без амперсанда?

Tags: c++, c, указатели

Если я хочу, чтобы функция изменяла передаваемое значение ,например, обычного int , я использую амперсанд.

Но если передаю ,например, указатель на int, то никакого амперсанда не потребуется.

В отладчике VS перед значением указателя стоит адрес: 0x012ff8d0 {4}.

Вроде бы это адрес той переменной, на которую указывает p, но не адрес самой p . Почему не нужно передавать адрес указателя, ведь он тоже где-то хранится? Играет ли в этом роль одинарной косвенности?

```
void k1(int* p,int *j)
{
    *j++;
    (*p)++;

}

int main()
{

    int *p = 0;
    int k = 4;
    int j = 6;
    p = &k;
    k1(p,&j); // не передаю адрес указателя

    return 0;
}
```

У меня бы не возник этот вопрос, и я бы так дальше и передавал указатели в функцию без лишних вопросов, но если бы не следующий случай:

```
struct ivector3d
{
    int *array;
};

void scale(ivector3d v, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        v.array[i] *= k;
}
int main()
{
    struct ivector3d iv3d;
    int a[3] = { 1,1,1 };
    iv3d.array = a;
    scale(iv3d, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Создаю переменную `iv3d` типа `struct ivector3d`. Создал инициализированный единицами массив `а`, и поставил на `а` указатель.

В аргументах функции scale передал копию `iv3d`. Но его поле - указатель изменил и оригинальное значение, хоть была передана копия структурной переменной. Видимо срабатывают те же причины , что и в примере выше.
 Так почему же указателям можно передаваться без & и изменить своё оригинальное значение?

Comment: потому что выполняется действие над обьектом, адрес которого содержит указатель, и не важно какой указатель его содержит. Этих указателей могут быть сколь угодно, и можно через любой из них модифицировать обьект..  Одним словом через указатель вы указываете на обьект, с которым хотите работать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас во втором случае передается копия, но в копии-то передается адрес - так же, как в первом случае вы передали в виде `p` адрес переменной `k`.

Здесь же копия содержит адрес массива `a`, каковой вы и меняете. Если вы поменяете само поле `array` внутри функции - на исходном объекта это не отразится (потому что вы поменяете его в копии). Но вы же меняете не переданную копию, а место в памяти, на которое копия указывает.

*Значением* вашего `p` является адрес `k`, значение самой переменной `p` после вызова не изменяется.

*Значением* вашего `v` по сути является адрес `a`, значение которого после вызова также не изменяется.

Вот, [убедитесь сами](http://ideone.com/QCyumi):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void k1(int* p,int *j)
{
    *j++;
    (*p)++;

}

struct ivector3d
{
    int *array;
};

void scale(ivector3d v, int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        v.array[i] *= k;
}


int main()
{
    int *p = 0;
    int k = 4;
    int j = 6;
    p = &k;
    cout << "p before: " << p << ", after: ";
    k1(p,&j); // не передаю адрес указателя
    cout << p << endl;

    struct ivector3d iv3d;
    int a[3] = { 1,1,1 };
    iv3d.array = a;
    cout << "iv3d.array before: " << iv3d.array << ", after: ";
    scale(iv3d, 2);
    cout << iv3d.array << endl;

}
```

Как видите, оригиналы остались неизменны, никаких чудес нет...